# Creating a table-like grid without using table

Tags: html, css, css-tables, tabular

Please see my awesome graphic below which is neither too scale or complete. BUT, I wanted to show the structure I'm going for instead of describing it.

I am creating a space rental system wherein a calendar, structured similarly to the below image, both shows the "taken" spots and also allows a user to click an "open" slot to reserve it themselves. I don't need help with the functionality though, just the layout.

Since this is tabular data at it's finest, with headers and everything, I was able to easily create the desired layout that way. However, tables render from left to right, so in the example below, it renders SPACE 1 9:00am, SPACE 2 9:00am, SPACE 3 9:00am, etc. I need it to actually render SPACE 1 9:00am, SPACE 1 10:00am, etc.
The reason is that in order to make each reservation into a "block" represented by the blue squares below, I need to be able to loop through the columns vertically and not through the rows horizontally.
I also want the columns to be a consistent width and be flexible if more spaces are added or if one/some are removed down the road.

I've been playing with flexbox, which I've barely used before, and I'm having no luck at all. I'm not even sure that's the right direction.

My question would be either 1) is there a way to get a standard table to load the way I want or 2) how can I do this without tables?

[image: Space Rental Grid Example]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bootstrap's grid system will fit your needs. http://getbootstrap.com/css/

You can create a grid like structure by adding columns, up to 12 in a row, and locking those into rows.